# OCR of Chinese characters with probability

Tags: ocr

I have a collection of Chinese character images (with single characters, not text). I need a way to OCR them, i.e. to map them to Unicode.

However, a crucial fact is that many of the images are a bit blurred, or quite small. Thus, the algorithm (or library, or online service) should not just return one Unicode value, but some kind of probability vector which estimates the probability that the given image represents which character.

For example, the image

[image]

could have the following distribution:

- 咳 95%
- 骇 4%
- 该 1%

I'd rather not train a neural network myself, since I'm sure that all OCR models are probabilistic underneath. All I'm looking for is an OCR solution that exposes the probabilities for single characters.